# Navigation in WIndows App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8

How does Navigation in Windows Apps work?When I call `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));` (calling MainPage) from say,`Page1` ,does my `MainPage.xaml` file loads first and all the `buttons` and `textbox`,etc are loaded and their content updated OR  does my `MainPage.xaml.cs` file runs first?If MainPage.xamal.cs runs first then `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` method runs first or the `constructor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is what actually creates the `Page1` object. There is no object before that, so no other methods could be invoked. And so, the constructor is called first, to create the object.

Inside the constructor, there is a call to the `InitializeComponent()` method which is automatically generated and is responsible for loading the XAML of the page. So, it's part of the constructor, basically.

The `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` comes after the constructor has completed and the XAML has been loaded.